# How to make a weather command using discord.py v1.4.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, openweathermap

In case you would like to make a `weather` command using discord.py and have a cool addition to your bot, I got you covered, I have answered below on how to create a `weather` command in discord.py.

Comment: This is quite broad, it seems more like a tutorial or guide. Please see [help/on-topic], [ask].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We will be making a command which will work like this -

[image: example]

---

Starting off, we are going to be using [openweahtermap](https://openweathermap.org/api) API, which requires an API key, you can get one for free by simple logging in to their [website](https://home.openweathermap.org/api_keys).

Once you have got the API key, you are all good to go.

The second step will be to start coding, we will import 1 module apart from discord.py which is `requests`. We can simply import it -

```
import requests
```

After importing we can define the following things so that it's easier to use them.

```
api_key = "your_api_key"
base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
```

The next step will be to create a command which takes `city` as an argument.

```
@client.command()
async def weather(ctx, *, city: str):
```

Afterwards, we can get the response of the website using `requests` and then read the response by using `json`. WE also define the channel in which the command is being used.

```
    city_name = city
    complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name
    response = requests.get(complete_url)
    x = response.json()
    channel = ctx.message.channel
```

Now, we check if the `city_name` is a valid city by using a simple `if` statement. We also use `async with channel.typing()` which shows that the bot is typing till the time that it fetches the contents from the website.

```
    if x["cod"] != "404":
        async with channel.typing():
```

Now we get the info about the weather.

```
            y = x["main"]
            current_temperature = y["temp"]
            current_temperature_celsiuis = str(round(current_temperature - 273.15))
            current_pressure = y["pressure"]
            current_humidity = y["humidity"]
            z = x["weather"]
            weather_description = z[0]["description"]
```

Now, once we have the info, we put the info inside a `discord.Embed` like so -

```
            weather_description = z[0]["description"]
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Weather in {city_name}",
                              color=ctx.guild.me.top_role.color,
                              timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,)
            embed.add_field(name="Descripition", value=f"**{weather_description}**", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Temperature(C)", value=f"**{current_temperature_celsiuis}°C**", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Humidity(%)", value=f"**{current_humidity}%**", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Atmospheric Pressure(hPa)", value=f"**{current_pressure}hPa**", inline=False)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://i.ibb.co/CMrsxdX/weather.png")
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")
```

After constructing the embed, we send it.

```
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        await channel.send("City not found.")
```

We also use an `else` statement which sends that the city is not found if the API is unable to fetch the weather of the city mentioned.

---

And with that you have successfully made a `weather` command!

If you do run into any errors or have any doubts, make sure to comment them below. I will try to help as much as I can.

Thanks!

Comment: You can try sending a web request or maybe throw in another library that can help you with the weather forecasting. Try this video https://youtu.be/i0YSbE15fEM

Comment: Though, instead of converting the temperature, you can  add a new variable called unit or however you want and this will contain the unit desired  like  `unit = 'units=metric' ` and the complete base url will look like   `complete_url= base_url + "appid=" + api_key + '&q=' + city_name + "&" + unit `   in this way you don't need tot bother with conversion