# OpenWeather API discord.py

Tags: discord, bots, discord.py, openweathermap

I recently came around OpeNweather API and I made a simple current weather command with help of this post: [How to make a weather command using discord.py v1.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63486570/how-to-make-a-weather-command-using-discord-py-v1-4-1?newreg=fc448cdfffa04c9f82aacf1e15a5e530)

I am pretty new to API so I need help with using Forecast API (documentation can be found here https://openweathermap.org/api/hourly-forecast)

I am using discord.py Rewrite for my bot

Comment: No-One is gonna write you a bunch of code, Get yourself on the track and write some code. If you stuck anywhere feel free to reach here. More info on how to ask a good question can be found here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can code it manualy using the
1. Request Module
and 
2. JSON Module 
to get started.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for inspiration of making this command. But with a little research and more details/learning how to retrieve data back from the API, got me here. I would like to help and share with you what I have come up with.

Basically, I used all the features available from the API. In my code below, it will look for temperature, humidity and pressure in the air. It uses a "get" method to retrieve this data, conditional that a valid city was provided in the command.

Simply get the key from the site and copy & paste in the "api_key" string. Hope this helps with your progress and though I may as well help out as I got the command working well.

```
api_key = "123abcmyweathercodeapitoken"
base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"


@client.command()
async def weather(ctx, *, city: str):

        city_name = city
        complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name
        response = requests.get(complete_url)
        x = response.json()
        channel = ctx.message.channel

        if x["cod"] != "404":

                y = x["main"]
                current_temperature = y["temp"]
                current_temperature_celsiuis = str(round(current_temperature - 273.15))
                current_pressure = y["pressure"]
                current_humidity = y["humidity"]
                z = x["weather"]
                weather_description = z[0]["description"]

                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title=f"Weather forecast - {city_name}",
                    color=0x7289DA,
                    timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,
                )
                embed.add_field(
                    name="Description",
                    value=f"**{weather_description}**",
                    inline=False)
                embed.add_field(
                    name="Temperature(C)",
                    value=f"**{current_temperature_celsiuis}°C**",
                    inline=False)
                embed.add_field(
                    name="Humidity(%)", value=f"**{current_humidity}%**", inline=False)
                embed.add_field(
                    name="Atmospheric Pressure(hPa)",
                    value=f"**{current_pressure}hPa**",
                    inline=False)
                embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")

                await channel.send(embed=embed)

        else:
                await channel.send(
                    f"There was no results about this place!")
```